# Start program minimized from task scheduler not working

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule the start of `outlook.exe` minimized, but the task does not launch the program. 
I created the task with the path 
`%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` and arguments `/C start "" /MIN "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"`. Trigger set to `work station unlock`

The log shows the task launched successfully but outlook never launched.

Comment: Unless you have it set to only run when user logged on it will be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the logged on user can mess with the logged on user. Someone else (including schedule tasks that aren't acting directly as you logged in) may not affect the keys/mouse/screen of the logged on user.

It not really designed as a security feature although it is one. Its designed to prevent poorly designed programs from annoying you.

So if you don't set the program to *Run Only When User Logged In* it will run invisible. If you start a program on another computer it will be invisible.

**You can't mess with the logged on user**.

There are many questions, particularly on StackOverflow.com, asking how to mess with users. They get closed.

**History**

In the early days of MSDos and Windows Microsoft made doing anything you wanted as a programmer easy. Programmers were trusted. They learnt they couldn't trust programmers.